# Calling a method from inside a view without using "this" keyword?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, scope

My backbone code seems to have a crazy number of `this.methodCall()` type of invocations and I'd love to be able to drop the `this`, and just call `methodCall()` directly from inside the View.

See the below code:

```
app.Main = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: '#main-div',

    // how do I call this function without invoking "this"?
    setPageCookies: function () {
        console.log('setting page cookies called!');
    },

    initialize: function () {
        // saw this online as a possible solution, but only seems to affect the scope of "this" 
        _.bindAll(this, 'setPageCookies');

        // this works:
        this.setPageCookies();

       // HOWEVER, I'd like to be able to call it like this instead:
       setPageCookies();

    }

});
```

Comment: You could use `bind` with the normal browser compatibility caveats.

Comment: You're doing object oriented programming, `this` is an important part of it. Is there any concrete reason to avoid it apart from laziness?

Comment: Not really laziness just for the sake of cleaner code. I feel like having "this" a thousand times on the page is redundant

Comment: It's not. `this.a()` and `a()` are two very different things. That's why the distinction is necessary. By removing the `this` in front of `setPageCookies()` you make it impossible to use `this` inside of `setPageCookies()`, unless you pass `this` as the first argument or `bind` `setPageCookies()`, which I guarantee will make your code more messy than just using `this` would be (not to mention harder to follow and reason about)

Comment: Well, it has a specific meaning, which makes it not "redundant".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly - `this.setPageCookies()` and `setPageCookies()` have drastically different meanings.

The way to achieve calling `setPageCookies()` without `this` would be to make `setPageCookies` a function declaration:

```
function setPageCookies() {

}

Backbone.View.extend({ 
  setPageCookies: setPageCookies,
  initialize: function() {
    setPageCookies()
  }
});
```

However, now you can't use `this` instead of `setPageCookies` - unless you use `bind`, or unless you write a complicated wrapper around `setPageCookies: setPageCookies` which takes the `this` value and passes it as a first argument.. or something. Which makes me ask - why do you want to achieve this?

Comment: If your making `setPageCookies` a global function then why assign it to the View's prototype?

Comment: Because if you use CommonJS (which I do), then `setPageCookies` is not global. Also, because I wanted to preserve the meaning of OP's code, which assigns `setPageCookies` to the prototype.

Comment: alright, so all the solutions are even messier than what I'm trying to fix. Thanks for the help.